# Javascript onclick event to write different text to an element with each click

Tags: javascript, onclick

What Javascript code can I use to write to the HTML DOM? I want to create a button which each time I click it, it writes different text to a document element? Example;

first click:

```
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML= "This is is the initial text."
```

second click:

```
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML= "This text replaces the initial text"
```

third click:

```
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML= "This text replaces the text from the second click"
```

and so forth and so forth...

All without 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to hire someone?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all the text options into an array.

Set up a variable that counts up with each click.

Call the text from the array using the number of the counter.

Some code:

```
var counter = 0;
var theArray = new Array("This is is the initial text.", "This text replaces the initial text", "This text replaces the text from the second click");

function clicked(){
   document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML= theArray[counter++];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of all the available text line available.

Then on click of button, generate a random number and replace with that index value from array.

```
var contentArray = ["This is is the initial text.", "This text replaces the initial text",    "This text replaces the text from the second click"],
length = countArray.length;

$(btn).bind('click',function(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = contentArray[randomNumber];
});
```